# How to inject a controller to a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Normally the service is injected in a controller.

**controller.js**

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .factory('myService', function($http){

      var myService = {
           get: get
      };         

      return myService;          

      function get(){
           // Get function.
      }

});
```

**service.js**

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('myController', function(myService) {

    myService.get();

});
```

**But it is possible to reverse the way? To Inject a controller to a service?**

Comment: Why would you want to? I'm not sure what scenario this would be useful in.

Comment: Im using angular-material `mdDialog` and i want a clean structure of a controllers. Basically `mdDialog` is called in a ctrl1 and  controller for that `mdDialog` template is within that same controller which is  `ctrl1` and i would like that the controller provided for `mdDialog` is in a different files so i would like to put the mdDialog inside a service so other controllers may use it. This will help me reused code effectively.

Comment: Instead of injecting a controller in a service, export the functionalities that are in your controller to another service and inject it the service. For instance, if controller C has functionality A and you want to inject in service S. So, Export functionality A to ServiceA and then injects ServiceA in S.

Comment: Yes, what @Dimitri said is correct. Injecting a controller into a service would defeat the entire purpose of a dependency injection system!

Comment: @Dimitri If you dont mind giving some simple demo it is much appreciated, im just recently studying angularjs.

Comment: Well, in your case, you do need to put the mdDialog inside a service. If you define the mdDialogController in his file, you just need to import this file in all the controllers that are going to use it. For each controller, you define a new mdDialog by passing the controller you just created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight answer would be No. You don't inject a controller to a service or anywhere else for that matter. The real question is why would you want to do that?

// Update

Assuming you are referring to https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog.
The `mdDialog` service expects a controller function, you could probably pass it a reference to a function.

Example:

```
angular.module('app',[])
  .factory('myService', function(){
    return {
      myMdDialogCtrl: function($scope, $mdDialog, items){
        // Controller for MD Dialog
      }
    }
  })
  .controller('ctrl1', function($scope, $mdDialog, myService){
    $mdDialog.show({
      ...
      controller: myService.myMdDialogCtrl
    })
  })
  .controller('ctrl2', function($scope, $mdDialog, myService){
    $mdDialog.show({
      ...
      controller: myService.myMdDialogCtrl
    })
  })
```

Comment: oh yes, sad to say it is, my reason is in the comment section above

Comment: I never thought it would be possible to pass a function in a controller for `$mdDialog`. Big thanks about it!